# Сайт не масштабируется на весь экран

Tags: html

Как сделать так, чтобы при открытии на телефоне страница сайта открывалась на весь экран?

Вот так сейчас выглядит мой сайт:

[image: Страница сайта на мобильном]

Comment: meta viewport прописать

Comment: Здравствуйте. Вас не смущает, что на вашей картинке ошибка показана? Предлагаю исправить ошибку, чтобы сайт хоть как-нибудь корректно отображался, а затем добавить здесь новый пример.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно сделать страницу адаптивной при помощи [@media запроса](http://htmlbook.ru/css/value/media).